# The Java Pattern and Matcher Regex curiosity

Tags: java, regex

Recently, I have been doing a lot of coding on regex. I have assumed the pattern goes this way(code sample1) all along until I tried it as in code sample2:

***CODE SAMPLE 1***

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([\\w]+)(?=\\s)|(?<=\\*)(.+?)(?=\\)|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
String sub1 = null;
String sub2 = null;

while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        sub1 = matcher.group(1);
        System.out.println(sub1);
    }
    else if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        sub2 = matcher.group(2);
        System.out.println(sub2);
    }
}
```

That works fine, producing the result. Meanwhile, when I change the structure as shown below:

***CODE SAMPLE 2***

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([\\w]+)(?=\\s)|(?<=\\*)(.+?)(?=\\)|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
//note please, though I have taken out the String definition it still gives the same result even If I had defined them here like I did in code1
while (matcher.find()) {
    String sub1 = matcher.group(1);
    String sub2 = matcher.group(2);
    System.out.println(sub1);
    System.out.println(sub2);
}
```

I realize that sometimes, the sub1 is null and sometimes the sub2 is null. Any clear, concise explanations as to how Matcher works internally ?

Comment: You do realize that those two pieces of code are equivalent except that the second one does not have null checks? I'm not entirely clear what your question has to do with regex

Comment: this regex will capture first alternative in group(1) and second in group(2), so in your first code sample you check which one is not null to get result, in second you try to get both, when one of them is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first code sample is equivalent to the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^([\\w]+)(?=\\s)|(?<=\\*)(.+?)(?=\\)|$)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(word);
while (matcher.find()) {
     String sub1 = matcher.group(1);
     String sub2 = matcher.group(2);
     if(sub1 != null) System.out.println(sub1);
     else if(sub2 != null) System.out.println(sub2); 
}
```

Basically, `Matcher.group` returns `null` when the group that you are referencing (in this case `1` or `2`) does not have a corresponding position in the search string.

The first example prevents the `null`s from being printed out by guarding the `println` statement with an `if(... != null)` check, which this code sample, in the style of your second example, also accomplishes.

Comment: (These two code samples are not equivalent, because your code executes the second `if` when `sub1 != null` while the OPs code won't.)

Comment: @steffen Whoops. I'll fix that